# yii pdfable data getting cut off at bottom

Tags: php, pdf, yii, pdf-generation

I am creaing a pdf using pdfable in Yii. I have managed to create the pdf document however on each page there is data being cut off if I set a margin for the top and bottom of each page. In my controller

```
$pdf = $this->createPdf();
        $pdf->setOptions(array('orientation'=>'Landscape',
                'margin-top'    => 5,
                'margin-right'  => 10,
                'margin-bottom' => 5,
                'margin-left'   => 10,
                )
            );
        $this->layout = 'pdf';
        $pdf->renderPage('pdf',array('results'=>$asaareaList));

        $pdf->send('ProjectReport_'.date('M-Y').'.pdf');
```

in my view

```
<head>
<style type='text/css'>

@media print{thead{display:table-header-group; margin-bottom:2px;}}
@page{margin-top:1cm;margin-left:1cm;margin-right:1cm;margin-bottom:1.5cm;}}

.odd {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5F1F4;
}
.even {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
}
table tbody tr:hover{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lightgreen;
}
table tbody tr{
    font-size:10pt;
}
body
{
  margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;

}

.grey{
    background: lightgrey;
}

.center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.size{
    font-size:15px;
}

table{
    padding-botton:30px;
}
thead{
    font-size:11px;
     font-weight: normal;
}

</style>
</head>
<!-- <body onload="window.print();window.close();">-->
<body>
<h1 class="grey center">Project Report</h1>
<table>
<?php 
$count = 0;
$class= null;
foreach($results as $key=>$data) {
?>

<tr class="grey size">
    <th colspan=12><?=$key ?></th>
</tr>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Actual End Date</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>%</th>
        <th>% Planned</th>
        <th>KM</th>
        <th>KM Planned</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th width="150">AREA</th>
        <th>PROJ INFO</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($data as $column=>$q) {   ?>

    <?php 
        $class = ($count % 2 === 0) ? 'odd' : 'even';
        $this->renderPartial('_report',array('data'=>$q,'class'=>$class));
        $count++;
    }
    ?>
</tbody>


<?php }
?>
</table>
</body>
```

the pdf result as you can see in picture near the bottom the data is cut off.
[image]

the second picture the css for heading does not go all the way acroos not sure why?
[image]

Comment: This looks like a CSS issue. Have you tried to render a PDF preview through `$this->render()` in the controller (See the example that came with Pdfable)? Is it also cut off? If not, then it's an issue with `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: im not sure what you mean. html view is fine also printing from html is fine too.